# estimating the midpoint of two dates

Tags: r, date

I like to know what is the midpoint of 12 months and 5years 6months ? in years.

This is how i calculate this value.

Step1 : Converting 5years 6 months to days : 5 * 365.25 + 6 * 30 = 2007 days

Step2 : Converting 12 months to days : 365.25 days

Step3 : Subtracting 12 months in days (Step2) from Step1. : 2007days - 365.25days = 1642days

Step4 : 1642/2 = 821 day.

Step5 : 2007 - 821 = 1186 = 3.24 years

Like to confirm if this correct ?

Comment: @Mark, i have updated to my question (..in years), hope this is specific ?

Comment: Do you have a programming related question? If not, you may consider asking elsewhere. Good luck!

Comment: @jpsmith, yes, I am wondering if my logic is correct ?

Comment: in that case, I would assume it would be `(2007 / 365.25)/2`

Comment: @Mark,  (2007/365.25)/2 is midpoint of 0 years - 5years 6 months.  and not the midpoint of 12months - 5years 6months ?  Is is it not ?

Comment: ah okay. The midpoint of 12 months (i.e. 1 year) and 5 years and 6 months (i.e. 5.5 years) is `1 + (5.5 - 1) / 2` = 3.25

Comment: So you want a range. There are two types of date ranges. One, and also what you are doing, is based on the exact number of days. 1 year for example has 365.25 days in this approach. The other approach is taking leap years into account, so one year has 365, and others 366 days. For this approach you need exact start and end dates. The `lubridate` package in R can calculate durations in both ways. If you want the second approach, using `lubridate` is the way to go. If you are happy with the first approach, your calculation is ok (although saying 1 month = 30 days seems very  rough to me!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer this particular question, you can use the duration class of lubridate:

```
library(lubridate)

mean(c(duration(1, units = "years"), duration(5.5, units = "years"))) |> as.duration()
# [1] "102562200s (~3.25 years)"
```

Answer (score 3):

The midpoint of two dates is their mean and the R `mean` function does work on vectors of Date class:

```
dates <- as.Date(c("2005-08-01", "2007-06-22")); 
mean(dates)
## [1] "2006-07-12"
```